# RegisterClientScriptBlock issue when setting warning on repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have some scripts that appear when a field is left blank or with a 0 in an asp.net web form. The warnings are triggering correctly, however the submission does not stop when the script appears. The save button continues to saving the item after it send the "please enter option order" warning. So the prompt appears, but the webform continues processing the save request. I think my brackets may be off. I can't seem to find the issue, does anyone see where I am making a mistake? I'm fairly confident it has something to do with my brackets, but I have not used a textbox inside of a repeater to set a warning/scriptblock before, so may be wrong.I need the page to stop processing the save once the "please enter option order" message appears. The page does stop when the "please enter a stem" triggers if that field is blank, hence my belief it's about the bracket location.

protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
con.Open();

var dtOptionsData = (DataSet)ViewState["dtOption"];
for (var i = 0; i < RptOptions.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var tbOptionOrder = (RptOptions.Items[i].FindControl("OptionOrder") as TextBox);
    //dtOptionsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Option Order"] = tbOptionOrder.Text;

    if (tbOptionOrder.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage",
            "alert('Please Enter Option Order');", true);
    }
    if (tbOptionOrder.Text == "0")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage",
            "alert('Please Enter Option Order');", true);
    }
}

    if (stemTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage",
            "alert('Please Enter a Stem');", true);
    }

else

        try
        {
            //get revision header id to insert on original item
            SqlCommand cmdOriginalHeaderID = new SqlCommand("select distinct item_header_id from item_header where item_id = @item_id", con);
            cmdOriginalHeaderID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", cloneItemID.Text);
            var OriginalHeaderID = cmdOriginalHeaderID.ExecuteScalar();

            //sql cmd1 is for item header info
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Update item_header set item_id = @item_id, old_item_id = @old_item_id, item_stem = @item_stem, modified_by = @modified_by, modified_datetime = getdate(), language = @language,solution = @solution, item_status_id = (select distinct s.item_status_id from item_status s left join item_header h on h.item_status_id = s.item_status_id where s.item_status_desc = @status), item_ownership_type_id = (select distinct o.item_ownership_id from item_ownership_type o left join item_header h on o.item_ownership_id = h.item_ownership_type_id where o.item_ownership_desc = @ownership)  ,market_segment_id = (select distinct m.market_segment_id from market_segment m left join item_header h on m.market_segment_id = h.market_segment_id where m.market_segment_name = @marketsegment) , mcs_code_id = (select distinct m.mcs_code_id from mcs_code m left join item_header h on m.mcs_code_id = h.mcs_code_id where m.mcs_code = @mcsid), item_type_id = (select distinct t.item_type_id from type_item t left join item_header h on t.item_type_id = h.item_type_id where t.item_type_desc = @typeid)," +
            "author_person_id = (Select person_id from [persons] p where p.first_Name +' ' + p.last_Name= @specialist) where item_header_id = @OriginalHeaderID", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", newIdTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_stem", stemTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modified_by", createdByTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_item_id", oldItemIDTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", txtLanguage.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", itemStatusDDL.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ownership", ownershipDDL.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marketsegment", marketDDL.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcsid", txtMCSid.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specialist", authorTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeid", ddlType.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solution", solutionTextBox.Text);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptOptions.Items)
            {

                var Option = (item.FindControl("Option") as TextBox).Text;
                var OptionOrder = (item.FindControl("OptionOrder") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var Key = (item.FindControl("Key") as CheckBox).Checked;
                var itemDetailID = (item.FindControl("DetailID") as TextBox).Text;
                //var ItemRefID = (item.FindControl("ItemRefID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");


                var optionsCmd = new SqlCommand("MERGE item_detail AS [target] USING (VALUES(@OriginalHeaderID, @Option, @OptionOrder, @Key, @ItemDetailID))  AS source(sitemheaderid, soption, soptionorder, soptionkey, sItemDetailID) ON [target].item_header_id = source.sItemHeaderID  AND [target].item_detail_id = source.sItemDetailID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [target].[option] = source.soption, [target].option_order = source.soptionorder, [target].option_key = source.soptionkey, [target].[weight] = source.soptionkey, [target].modified_datetime = GETDATE() WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(item_header_id, [option], option_order, option_key,[weight], created_datetime) VALUES(source.sItemHeaderID, source.soption, source.soptionorder, source.soptionkey,source.soptionkey, getdate());", con);

                optionsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDetailID", itemDetailID);
                optionsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option", Option);
                optionsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OptionOrder", OptionOrder);
                optionsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", Key);
                optionsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                //refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemRefID", ItemRefID);
                optionsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            var deletedOptions = ViewState["deleteOptions"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedOptions))
            {
                var deleteOptionsCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from item_detail where item_detail_id in (" + deletedOptions.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteOptionsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptRefs.Items)
            {

                var referenceid = (item.FindControl("refID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var pages = (item.FindControl("Pages") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var Verification = (item.FindControl("Verification") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var ItemRefID = (item.FindControl("ItemRefID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");


                var refsCmd = new SqlCommand("MERGE item_reference AS [target] USING (VALUES(@OriginalHeaderID, @refID, @Pages, @Verification, @ItemRefID)) AS source(sItemHeaderID, sRefID, sPages, sVerification, sItemReferenceID) ON [target].item_header_id = source.sItemHeaderID AND [target].reference_id = source.sRefID AND [target].item_reference_id = source.sItemReferenceID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [target].[pages] = source.sPages, [target].verification = source.sVerification,  [target].modified_datetime = GETDATE() WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(item_header_id, reference_id, [pages], verification, created_datetime)VALUES(source.sItemHeaderID, source.sRefID, source.sPages, source.sVerification, getdate());", con);

                refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refID", referenceid);
                refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pages", pages);
                refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Verification", Verification);
                refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                refsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemRefID", ItemRefID);
                refsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            var deletedRefs = ViewState["deleteRefs"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedRefs))
            {
                var deleteRefsCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from item_reference where item_reference_id in (" + deletedRefs.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteRefsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptComments.Items)
            {

                //var commentid = (item.Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
                var comments = (item.FindControl("comments") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var Specialist = (item.FindControl("Specialist") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var ComID = (item.FindControl("ComID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");

                var commentsCmd = new SqlCommand("MERGE item_comment AS target USING (Values (@ComID)) AS source(sItemCommentID)  ON target.item_comment_id = source.sItemCommentID   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.comment = @comments WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (item_header_id, comment, specialist_person_id, created_datetime) VALUES(@originalheaderid,@comments,(Select person_id from [persons] p where p.first_Name +' ' + p.last_Name = @Specialist),getdate());", con);
                commentsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", comments);
                commentsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specialist", Specialist);
                commentsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComID", ComID);
                commentsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                commentsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            var deletedComments = ViewState["deleteComments"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedComments))
            {
                var deleteCommentsCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from item_comment where item_comment_id in (" + deletedComments.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteCommentsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptEnemy.Items)
            {


                var enemyID = (item.FindControl("EnemyID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var enemyHeaderID = (item.FindControl("EnemyHeaderID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var ItemStem = (item.FindControl("ItemStem") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var Type = (item.FindControl("Type") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var TypeID = (item.FindControl("TypeID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var SocID = (item.FindControl("SocID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");

                var enemyCmd = new SqlCommand("MERGE social_order AS target  USING (VALUES (@OriginalHeaderID,@SocID, @EnemyHeaderID, @TypeID)) AS source(sItemHeaderID, sSocID, sEnemyItemHeaderID, sSocialOrderTypeID) ON target.item_header_id = source.sItemHeaderID   AND target.related_item_header_id = source.sEnemyItemHeaderID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.social_order_type_id = @TypeID, target.modified_datetime = GETDATE() WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (item_header_id, related_item_header_id, social_order_type_id, created_datetime) VALUES (@OriginalHeaderID, @EnemyHeaderID, @TypeID, GETDATE());", con);
                //enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnemyID", enemyID);
                enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnemyHeaderID", enemyHeaderID);
                //enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemStem", ItemStem);
                //enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", Type);
                enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", TypeID);
                enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocID", SocID);
                enemyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                enemyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            var deletedEnemies = ViewState["deleteEnemies"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedEnemies))
            {
                var deleteEnemiesCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from social_order where soc_entry_id in (" + deletedEnemies.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteEnemiesCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptExhibits.Items)
            {

                //var commentid = (item.Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
                var exhibitID = (item.FindControl("exhibitID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                var itemExhibitID = (item.FindControl("ItemExID") as TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''");
                //exhibitentry += "(" + headerid + "," + "'" + exhibitID + "'),";
                var CmdExhibits = new SqlCommand("MERGE item_exhibit AS target USING (VALUES (@OriginalHeaderID, @exhibitID, @itemExhibitID)) AS source(sItemHeaderID, sExhibitID, sItemExID) ON target.item_header_id = source.sItemHeaderID AND target.exhibit_id = source.sExhibitID and target.item_exhibit_id = source.sItemExID WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (item_header_id, exhibit_id, created_datetime) VALUES (@OriginalHeaderID, @exhibitID, getdate());", con);
                CmdExhibits.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exhibitID", exhibitID);
                CmdExhibits.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                CmdExhibits.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemExhibitID", itemExhibitID);
                CmdExhibits.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            var deletedExhibits = ViewState["deleteExhibits"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedExhibits))
            {
                var deleteExhibitsCMD = new SqlCommand("delete from item_exhibit where item_exhibit_id in (" + deletedExhibits.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteExhibitsCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            //string reventry = "";
            //var cmdRevs = new SqlCommand("select item_header_id from item_header where item_id = @item_id", con);
            //cmdRevs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", newIdTextBox.Text);
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptRevision.Items)
            {
                var Change = (item.FindControl("Change") as TextBox).Text;
                var Reason = (item.FindControl("Reason") as TextBox).Text;
                var PersonID = (item.FindControl("PersonID") as TextBox).Text;
                var Specialist = (item.FindControl("Specialist") as TextBox).Text;
                var ItemRevID = (item.FindControl("IrID") as TextBox).Text;

                var cmdRevisions = new SqlCommand("MERGE item_revision AS target   USING (Values (@ItemRevID)) AS source(sItemRevisionID) ON target.item_revision_id = source.sItemRevisionID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.change = @change, target.reason = @reason, target.specialist_person_id = (Select person_id from [persons] p where p.first_Name +' ' + p.last_Name = @Specialist) , target.modified_datetime = GETDATE() WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (item_header_id, change, reason, specialist_person_id, created_datetime) VALUES(@OriginalHeaderID, @Change, @Reason, (Select person_id from [persons] p where p.first_Name +' ' + p.last_Name = @Specialist),getdate());", con);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", Change);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", Reason);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", PersonID);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specialist", Specialist);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalHeaderID", OriginalHeaderID);
                cmdRevisions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemRevID", ItemRevID);
                cmdRevisions.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //reventry += "(" + headerid + "," + "'" + Change + "'," + "'" + Reason + "'," + "" + PersonID + "),";
            }

            var deletedRevisions = ViewState["deleteRevisions"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deletedRevisions))
            {
                var deleteRevisionsCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from item_revision where item_revision_id in (" + deletedRevisions.Trim(',') + ")", con);
                deleteRevisionsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            //confirmation message and clear form after hitting save. 
            string msgstring = "You Have Successfully Edited this item";
            string content = "window.onload=function(){ alert('";
            content += msgstring;
            content += "');";
            content += "window.location='";
            content += Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            content += "';}";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SucessMessage", content, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "") + "'); ", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

}

Comment: It's not clear how your code is supposed to flow, but there are some definite problems with the brackets.  Can you post the whole method?

Comment: The rest of the method is completely different in what it does, the validation looking for blanks is where I am stuck. It's fairly long, but there it is. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to get this to work, adding the answer in case anyone else ever encounters a similar issue.

```
 var dtOptionsData = (DataSet)ViewState["dtOption"];
        for (var i = 0; i < RptOptions.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var tbOptionOrder = (RptOptions.Items[i].FindControl("OptionOrder") as TextBox);
            dtOptionsData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Option Order"] = tbOptionOrder.Text;

            if (tbOptionOrder.Text == "")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                    "alertMessage",
                    "alert('Please Enter Option Order');", true);
                return;
            }
            if (tbOptionOrder.Text == "0")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                    "alertMessage",
                    "alert('Please Enter Option Order');", true);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (stemTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                "alertMessage",
                "alert('Please Enter a Stem');", true);
            return;
        }

        try
```